# How can I delete branch links?

Tags: branch.io

I am using branch.io for generating short links for custom domain and alias, 
where alias is a sequential 6 character alphanumeric string.

The final link looks something like this: domain.co/AAABBB

For testing, custom domain integration, I used the custom domain in the branch.io test environment. 
Now while going live, I am using the same custom domain but some of the links are not getting generated because of the previously generated test links.

As a result, I would like to delete old test links that are using the custom domain. Can you please help me with the delete rocedure as I haven't found any yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** it is now possible to delete links. Check docs.branch.io for more.

---

Alex from Branch.io here: there is no way to delete Branch links. This is by design, because missing links could lead to systemic data integrity issues with your app environment. However, your case is somewhat unusual and I understand what you are trying to do.

There are two ways you could address this:

1. If you have no critical production data/links, just make a new Branch app configuration. Remove your custom domain from the old app and add it to the new one, update your Branch key in your app, and you can start over from scratch.
2. If you can't start over with a new app, you could use our API to [manually modify the parameters of your existing links](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/branch-deep-linking-public-api#modifying-existing-deep-linking-urls). This would be a tedious and manual process so I wouldn't recommend it by choice, but it should get you what you need as last resort.

Comment: I have made a separate branch app for production. Also, I added a strategy to make the alias unique as well. Thanks for the quick reply

Comment: @Alex I have created a branch link https://teazer.app.link/d/WKSOqISORI and it got deleted automatically, how it can happen?

Comment: @srivastava it never should — sounds like something else going on. Could you write to our [integrations team](https://support.branch.io/support/tickets/new) with more details so we can debug?

Comment: Branch.io now allows deleting Quick Links.