# Revoke or deactivate or delete deep links of branch.io

Tags: java, android, android-studio, deep-linking, branch.io

Is there any way to deactivate or revoke or delete deep links of branch.io programmatically. So that next time when any one clicks on that link It will not work, like WhatsApp is doing..?? In this link "[How can I delete branch links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39832971/how-can-i-delete-branch-links)"  it's saying that either you reconfigure your app with new branch app configuration or modify manually your existing links. I don't want to do that I want to deactivate it completely.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I delete branch links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39832971/how-can-i-delete-branch-links)

Answer (score 0):

No, there is currently no way to deactivate or revoke Branch links programmatically.

I've gone ahead and submitted a feature request to Branch for this functionality on your behalf.